# user-input and ESS

Tags: r, emacs, ess

When you ask ESS to evaluate the following from a buffer (C-c, C-b, or similar)

```
par(ask=TRUE)
plot(1,1)
plot(2,1)
```

The interpreter goes into a infinite loop because ESS starts the R session with the argument --no-readline. The loop can be broken with C-g, but is there any way to get the interpreter to actually request user input?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to edit `ess-r-d.el` and remove the hard-coded `--no-runtime` option given to `R`, it is line 127 of the latest implementation.

Change

```
  (let* ((r-always-arg
      (if (or ess-microsoft-p (eq system-type 'cygwin))
          "--ess "
        "--no-readline "))
```

to

```
  (let* ((r-always-arg
      (if (or ess-microsoft-p (eq system-type 'cygwin))
          "--ess "))
```

If there is a compiled version, you have to compile the `.el` to generate and replace the binary `.elc` file.

The file may be (the location of the directory depends on your OS)

- in the `site-lisp` directory. Edit the `.el` file in emacs (^X^F) then do `M-x byte-compile-file` to generate the `.elc`.
- if you installed from the whole zip/tar source package, in the `lisp` directory. In this case, after the change, perform a `make` followed with a `make install`.

You need of course to have `write` access to the `.el` and `.elc` files.

If you do not feel comfortable with the compilation of the `.el` file, you may simply remove it (`.elc`) and use only the `.el` version (should be only a slight performance difference).

Comment: Well said. And you know what the blowhards on stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/ess-help would have said if the OP had asked them how to fix this? They'd have said "You shouldn't use readline in the first place, the built-in ESS functionality is better, blah blah blah." Because of course they know what's best for the user better than the user does. Thank you for documenting this patch, instead of lecturing the OP about what they "should" be doing.

Answer (score 0):

(Strategies gathered from Google and RSiteSearches):

Do you see the prompt : "hit Return" in any of your session windows? If so ... hit .

If not, then try clicking in the plot window.

And if that fails, you should get control back with c-G.

Edit: A further strategy, admittedly not solving the ESS-non-interactivity problem: If you want to hold for user input, then readLines can be used:

```
input=file("stdin")
print(readLines(input,1))
```

Comment: The prompt only appears AFTER hitting c-G, and c-G doesn't just break out of the loop that is waiting for user-input, it stops the execution of the remaining script.

Comment: So just to be clear, a plot window appears and despite clicking in the window to get focus to it, you do not see the prompt?

Comment: You are quite right. The script as I had it before, with just one plot executed without problem, when I started in a clean R session. I added a second plot to the original question, so that the problem I'm describing is reproducible.

Comment: I suggest you also ask on the ESS mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/ess-help